# Comparing and combining two images in c++ using open cv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, match

I have two pictures taken from two cameras disposed next to each other.The pictures are almost the same, but in one of them I have some rain drops and I need to compare and combine those two pictures in the same image in the end (eliminating of course the rains drops), as a result.

Actually I used a lot of methods that I found online but I did not get the result I need. First, I tried to find all the correspondence points and I found a lot of them and then, I tried to eliminate all the "bad" matches to have at the end only "good " points. And [here is the tutorial](https://qiita.com/wakaba130/items/b566f15a4f2cf1ce414f) I used.

Second, I used the [affine transformation method](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html) provided by OpenCV library to know the transformation that happened to these points from one image to the other and unfortunately I got a very wrong result. (I think since I have the points and their coordinates I need to know the matrix M itself now ).
Here is the code I tried and sorry if it is very well written since a newbie and this my first time with this kind of work.

```
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1;
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints2;
Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
cv::Ptr<cv::AKAZE> akaze = cv::AKAZE::create();
akaze->detectAndCompute(Src1, cv::Mat(), keypoints1, descriptors1);
akaze->detectAndCompute(Src2, cv::Mat(), keypoints2, descriptors2);

vector<vector<cv::DMatch>> knnmatch_points;
cv::BFMatcher match(cv::NORM_HAMMING);
match.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, knnmatch_points, 2);
const double match_par = 0.4; 
vector<cv::DMatch> goodMatch;
vector<cv::Point2f> match_point1;
vector<cv::Point2f> match_point2;
for (size_t i = 0; i < knnmatch_points.size(); ++i) {
  double distance1 = knnmatch_points[i][0].distance;
  double distance2 = knnmatch_points[i][1].distance;
  if (distance1 <= distance2 * match_par) {
    goodMatch.push_back(knnmatch_points[i][0]);
    match_point1.push_back(keypoints1[knnmatch_points[i][0].queryIdx].pt);
    match_point2.push_back(keypoints2[knnmatch_points[i][0].trainIdx].pt);
...
    srcTri[i] = Point2f(keypoints1[knnmatch_points[i][0].queryIdx].pt);
    dstTri[i] = Point2f(keypoints2[knnmatch_points[i][0].queryIdx].pt);

  }
}
cv::Mat masks;
cv::Mat H = cv::findHomography(match_point1, match_point2, masks, cv::RANSAC, 3);
vector<cv::DMatch> inlinerMatch;
for (size_t i = 0; i < masks.rows; ++i) {
  uchar *inliner = masks.ptr<uchar>(i);
  if (inliner[0] == 1) {
    inlinerMatch.push_back(goodMatch[i]);
  }
}
warp_mat = getAffineTransform(srcTri, dstTri);
warpAffine(Src2, warp_dst, warp_mat, warp_dst.size());
namedWindow(warp_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow(warp_window, warp_dst);
```

I think I can use other methods to get my result like binary search to find the error or gradient descent to minimize the system of equation but I am not really familiar with any of them .. so please if there is any help in this subject 
Thanks in advance and any help will be very appreciated

Comment: You should edit your post and add test images and a result image to understand what is "I got a very wrong result". This way people can give you better ideas and suggestions.

Comment: you cannot expect help if you don't provide images and result data. also, if both images show the same and all you want to do is get rid of the rain drops, why not just use the image without rain drops? I mean from your post I don't quite get why you need two cameras at all. and what do you mean with combine and compare both images? what's the purpose of this?

Comment: can you explain why you use srcTri and dstTri in `warp_mat = getAffineTransform(srcTri, dstTri);` instead of the goodMatch matches? Can you explain why you use affineTransformation instead of perspective transformation?